# I'm having a confusing 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'

Tags: python, flask

I'm having a very confusing FileNotFoundError.
This is the exact error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\opt\\flogger\\static\\images\\uploads\\ad142cb9-1d55-4cce-9bbc-a984344f65bb.png'
```

This is additional info about the error:

```
File "C:\Users\Kyrios\opt\flogger\blog\views.py", line 40, in post

 [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] Image.open(f).save(file_path)

File "C:\Users\Kyrios\opt\flogger\venv\Lib\site-packages\pil\Image.py", line 2161, in save

 [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
```

This is the code:

```
image_id = None

        if form.image.data:
            f = form.image.data
            image_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            file_name = image_id + '.png'
            file_path = os.path.join(
                BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH, file_name
            )
            Image.open(f).save(file_path)

            _image_resize(BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH, image_id, 600, 'lg')
            _image_resize(BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH, image_id, 300, 'sm')
```

The _image_resize function:

```
def _image_resize(original_file_path, image_id, image_base, extension):
    file_path = os.path.join(
        original_file_path, image_id + '.png'
    )
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    wpercent = (image_base / float(image.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
    image = image.resize((image_base, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    modified_file_path = os.path.join(
        original_file_path, image_id + '.' + extension + '.png'
    )
    image.save(modified_file_path)
    return
```

And this is the file path

```
BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH='C:\opt\flogger\static\images\uploads'
```

The directory exists but it keeps saying that it doesn't which is confusing. Is this a problem with the uuid module or is it something else? The imports are:

```
from flask import Blueprint, session, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, request
from slugify import slugify
import uuid
import os
from pil import Image
from settings import BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH
```

The settings.py:

```
import os

SECRET_KEY=os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
DB_USERNAME=os.environ['DB_USERNAME']
DB_PASSWORD=os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
DB_HOST=os.environ['DB_HOST']
DATABASE_NAME=os.environ['DATABASE_NAME']
DB_URI = f"mysql+pymysql://{DB_USERNAME}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_HOST}:3306/{DATABASE_NAME}"
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = DB_URI
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = os.environ['MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD']
BLOG_NAME = os.environ['BLOG_NAME']
BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH = os.environ['BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH']
```

ps. And oh the pil is in small letters is because PIL doesn't work it keeps getting the nomodule error, the file I found on my site-packages is in small letters

Comment: Just to confirm, you are absolutely certain that both `C:\opt\flogger` *and* `C:\Users\Kyrios\opt\flogger` exist and are different directories?

Comment: There's a good chance that `BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH='C:\opt\flogger\static\images\uploads'` is causing some of your headache. Can you try preceding the string literal with an `r`, as in `BLOG_POST_IMAGES_PATH=r'C:\opt\flogger\static\images\uploads'` Python is likely swallowing the backslashes, which the `r` should cure.

Comment: The string literal r didn't work it actually made the error much worse it doubled the '\'

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the answer is just replacing the 'C:\opt\flogger\static\images\uploads', with the actual full path. user Wander Nauta thanks for the insight